# Mentioning unpublished research paper in Statement of Purpose/Resume

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, cv, statement-of-purpose

I graduated two years ago with a BE degree. At that time, I did not have any plans for Ph.D./higher education, so I did not put any effort to publish my undergrad research work in any conference.

Now things have changed a lot, and I am applying to Ph.D. programs. To strengthen my research profile, I have entirely reviewed my undergrad dissertation, and manage to come up with a research paper out of it.

The problem is that there is no time to publish this paper as the paper submission date of a potential conference will open up next year, and my grad applications are due next month.

I wanted to know **how I can mention my unpublished research paper in my Statement of Purpose, Resume?** Considering that the research paper is highly relevant to the Ph.D. program I am applying to.

(Do I also need to mention the reason behind publishing my research work so late? like after two years)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly mention "work in progress" or "submitted, not yet accepted" and the like in your materials. Just label things for what they are. Two years isn't really a long time for research in most fields, so I wouldn't worry much about the time. It is also natural, if you have been working in the field to immerse yourself in that for a while.

But submitting the work is marginally better than not.